# Symfony, Call service in PHP Unit

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony

I have a unit test, where I need to call a service.

I did it that way:

```
<?php
namespace FM\PriceBundle\Tests\Service;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;

class PriceServiceTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    private $container;

    public function testFiulPrice()
    {
        self::bootKernel();
        $this->container = self::$kernel->getContainer();

        $productId = 1;
        $id = 1;
        $what = ['postal', 'departement', 'region', 'country', 'insee'];
        $date = new \DateTime('2016-06-23');

        $price = $this->container->get('fm.price.get')->fiulPrice($productId, $id, $what[0], $date);

        $this->assertNotEmpty($price);
    }
}
```

But I have this error:

> There was 1 error:
>
> 1) FM\PriceBundle\Tests\Service\PriceServiceTest::testFiulPrice 
>   Predis\Connection\ConnectionException: Connection refused [tcp://localhost:6379]

Comment: It seems an error in your service... Does it try to connect anywhere?

Comment: check the service parameters configuration for the test environment

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use redis in your app.

But I don't understand why do you want to implement test like this.

That test literally takes fixed data, an tries to get a result from external service that uses dependency (redis).

In my opinion, you need unit test for PriceService, another one for serivce registered as 'fm.price.get', and (maybe) the third one that use redis, but in this case you have to populate cache with some sample data.